# How to sniff packages of the entire network (not only broadcast)?

Tags: security, wireshark, sniffing

First of all thanks for dropping by!

I recently installed a XMPP Server named [Openfire](https://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/openfire/) in a Windows 8.1 machine. At the same time I was running Active Directory (**AD**) on Windows Server 2012 (**W2012**) in the same subnet. I configured the XMPP Server to authenticate users against AD but using no encryption (just plaintext, no SSL or STARTTLS) for this process. With [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) installed in the W2012 Server I sniffed the traffic between this two computers and was able to see the **clear password** for any authenticated user only by putting **LDAP** as search filter in Wireshark. As I said before this happened because of the plaintext authentication between server (Openfire) and client (Pidgin).

I tried to sniff that LDAP (Active Directory) packets from a third computer in the same subnet without any success, only received broadcast packets and other protocols such as ARP, LLMNR, etc. My question is: What procedure is needed to capture others computer's packets (not broadcast but LDAP or any other)? Maybe using a man-in-the-middle attack (**MitM**) or setting up the network adapter in **Promiscuous Mode**. Any help is welcome.

> This is not for hacking purposes, I'm just learning about sysadmin
>   and want to know how to take advantage from system's vulnerabilities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On a modern switched Ethernet network, you need to somehow convince the *switch* to send the packets to your port, not to the recipient's. This can be done with:

- Manual configuration: managed switches support "port mirroring" aka "SPAN", which sends a *copy* of a particular switch port's traffic to the mirror port (where you are).
- Attacks on the switch: ARP spoofing (targeted MITM), or CAM overflow (network-wide attack).
- Swap the switch with an old hub: your network will crawl, but at least you'll get *all* packets.

This is a bit easier with Wi-Fi, which is broadcast by nature.

Comment: So basically a "hacker" only will get my LDAP passwords by using the second entry (**targeted MITM** or **CAM overflow**)? Since he/she can't do the two remaining (My network is very small to replace devices in order to perform attacks). Anyway the real solution to my problem is to implement STARTTLS or SSL for athentication. Now, are you saying in Wi-Fi networks there is no need to MitM or CAM overflow to receive everyones packets? **Every packet** is send to everyone as broadcast even authentication ones?

Comment: @Ophion CooCoo for Cocoa Puffs!!

Comment: @Ophion: Well, it's fairly difficult to send a radio signal to only one receiver...